# Attempted import error in react when importing Typogaphy and TexxtField from MUI

Tags: reactjs

I work in  a group project in gitlab, and when i try to run yarn dev for my react project I get the following error:

> Attempted import error: '@mui/material/Typography' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Typography').

And the same error from TextField

This is how I import Typograpgy:

```js
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
```

Other imports works fine, but not `TextField` and `Typography`

Does anyone know the solution  for this problem? I am the only one in the group that gets this error

I have tried to import by using

```
import {Typography} from '@mui/material'
```

instead, but that doesn't work either

Comment: What version of mui you are using?

Comment: version: "5.11.9"